# Levenshtein edit-distance between rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have created the following empty DataFrame:

```
columns = ['Band','Tree','Foot']
rows = ['Hand', 'Foot', 'Shoulder']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=rows, columns=columns)
```

I want to calculate the distance between the columns and the rows and am currently using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk

def distance(x):
    i = x.index
    j = x.name
    return nltk.edit_distance(i,j)

df = df.apply(distance)
```

But this returns:

| - | - |
| --- | --- |
| Band | 4 |
| Tree | 4 |
| Foot | 4 |

I would like it to return the distance between the corresponding column and row for each cell.

|  | Band | Tree | Foot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hand | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| Foot | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| Shoulder | 7 | 7 | 7 |

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit_distance` expects 2 strings, so you have to iterate over the indexes. One option is to apply a lambda that does that on `df`:

```
df.apply(lambda col: [nltk.edit_distance(col.name, i) for i in col.index])
```

But, instead of filling in a DataFrame, I think it's simpler to first create a dictionary with the values; then build a DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({j: {i: nltk.edit_distance(i,j) for i in rows} for j in columns})
```

Output:

```
          Band  Tree  Foot
Hand         1     4     4
Foot         4     4     0
Shoulder     7     7     7
```